# Can i concurrently set MAPJOIN hint and STREAMTABLE hint?

Tags: hive

Can i use like this?

```
select /*+ MAPJOIN(t2)*//*+ STREAMTABLE(t1)*/
       t1.c1.
       t2.c1
from t1 
left outer join t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

And i am confuse about "STREAMTABLE" on different join keys.

For example:
t3 is biggest table,and t2 is secondary big table,t1 is smallest table.

```
select 
  /*+ STREAMTABLE(t2)*/
  t1.c3,
  t2.c2,
  t3.c3 
from t2 
left outer join 
t1 
on t2.c1=t1.c1 
left outer join 
t3 on t2.c2=t3.c2;
```

So if when t2 join t1 it's ok.But when t2 join t3,if t2 if still treated as big table?
How can handle this situation?

Comment: Do not use such hints at all. Cost-based optimizer will do this work. Use cost-based optimizer + statistics.

Comment: @leftjoin Hi,how can i do this?My hive version is 0.13.x?What should i do?

Comment: Upgrade. 0.14 Hive on Tez works much faster and no hints any more is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the following:

```
select /*+ MAPJOIN(t2), STREAMTABLE(t1)*/
   t1.c1.
   t2.c1
from t1 
left outer join t2
on t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

There are a non-trivial number of CBO-related defects that you might still run into, especially involving windowing functions and columnar formats in my experience.  It is therefore somewhat useful to know how to effectively apply hints.

Answer (score -1):

I think we dont need to provide MAPJOIN here as rest of tables except streamtable will buffered/cached into all nodes. So it automatically turns into mapjoin.